# C++: life-cycle of variables in namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

Can someone please explain to me the life cycle of a variable from a namespace? Let's say I have the following files:

file.h:

```
// ...
namespace variables{
    int x, y;
}
```

file.cpp:

```
#include "file.h"
using namespace variables;

int main(){
    ...
}
```

What are the scopes of `x` and `y`? I ask because, in a book I was reading (C++ Primer Plus), the author recommends `using namespace`s inside functions, and so I thought that they are defined at the point of the `using` command. However, when I do this:

B.h:

```
class B{
     // class stuff
};

namespace variables{
    int x, y;
}
```

and then in `main.cpp` (main program) and `B.cpp` (class implementation) I add the `#include "B.h"` line, I get an error that I have multiple definitions of `variables::x` and `variables::y`, even though there is no `using` in any file. What's the deal? Am I mixing up two different concepts?

Comment: Defining variables in your header file isn't such a hot idea, for starters.

Comment: That actually was my question. I was asking where the definition happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you directly declare variables in a namespace just like you did, they will simply exist as **global variables**.

Thus, the rules that apply for normal global variables also apply for those ones : they will exist for as long as the program run, and you should not define them in a header file.

include.h

```
namespace Variables
{
    extern int x;
    extern int y;
}
```

file.cpp

```
namespace Variables
{
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Writing `using namespace Variables` will simply allow you to access those variables by their name `x` and `y`, without having to prefix them with `Variables::`

Answer (score 2):

Namespace has *no* influence on variable's lifespan, so:

```
namespace variables{
    int x, y;
}

#include "file.h"
using namespace variables;

int main(){
    ...
}
```

> What are the scopes of x and y?

These variables are global, so their life time equals to life time of the entire application.

Remember, that `using namespace` is simply a shortcut to writing `NamespaceName::` in front of elements from this namespace.

Answer (score 2):

> I add the #include "B.h" line, I get an error that I have multiple definitions of variables::x and variables::y, even though there is no using in any file. What's the deal? Am I mixing up two different concepts?

Your variables are declared even if you do not explicitly import the namespace. The keyword `using` import namespaces or specific names within the current scope so that you don't have to prepend `X::` to access a defined element.

The life span of a variable is not affected by namespaces.